# Recursive use of Javascript returns undefined

Tags: javascript, recursion, functional-programming

I'm trying to write a recursive function with Javascript, but apparently I miss something and I cannot make it return at the point that I want.
In the following example, I would expect to see that baz=18 in the logs, however baz is undefined.

https://jsfiddle.net/n8fg1h3v/1/

Any ideas?

```
function foo(arr) {
  if (arr[0]==7) {
    return 18
  } else {
    arr = arr.slice(1,arr.length);
    foo(arr);
  }
}

var arr1 = [9,1,2,3,4,7,6];
var baz = foo(arr1);
console.log(baz)
```

Comment: Please note that while you can make reassignments (`arr = ...`) in Javascript wherever you want, it is quite uncommon within recursive algorithms. Pass the expression as an argument instead (`foo(arr.slice(...))`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a return of calling `foo` inside of the function.

```
return foo(arr);
```

```js
function foo(arr) {
    if (arr[0] == 7) {
        return 18;
    } else {
        arr = arr.slice(1, arr.length);
        return foo(arr);
    }
}

var arr1 = [9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 6];
var baz = foo(arr1);
console.log(baz)
```

Comment: do you like to use a default value if no `7` is in the array?

Comment: No, this was just a simple example to show and try to understand why my `if then else` statement with a `return` inside `if` did not work as I would have expected. With adding the `return foo(arr)` as you suggested it works fine in the simple example and also in my real problem. Thanks! (I cannot accept the answer for another ~10 min, I will do it just after that.)

Answer (score 0):

I would simply do this:

```js
function foo(arr) {
  var el = arr.find(el => el === 7);  
  return el ? 18 : '7 was not found';
}

var bar = foo([9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 6]);
console.log(bar);

var baz = foo([9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 6]);
console.log(baz);
```

Comment: i would use `some`, because it breaks the iteration, but it has nothing to do with recursion.

Comment: Also `Array.prototype.find()` breaks the iteration.. I understand your point about recursion, but here I do not think that it's necessary